# Inline-block for a right side div doesn't seem to be taking effect

Tags: css

I'm a newbie when it comes to CSS. I'm working with a HTML content which I would want to look like 3 columns in a single row. I've the following HTML with embedded style:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #main {
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
    }

    #left-side {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #in-the-middle {
        width: 60%;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #right-side {
        width: 20%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
    }

</style>

<div id="main">

    <div id="left-side" align="left">
        Hello left
    </div>
    <div id="in-the-middle" align="center">
        Hello center
    </div>
    <div id="right-side">
        Hello right
    </div>
</div>
```

Looks simple, but unfortunately the "Hello right" text gets displayed at the left side of the page. I have set the display for the #right-side to be inline-block, expecting it to show up adjacent to the "Hello center" div, but it doesn't seem to take effect. Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the elements become rendered inline, white-space in your HTML code will affect the rendering. Since there is whitespace between your `div`s, the browser will render several pixels of white spaces between them.

If you want to use `inline-block` without `float`, the solution is to remove the white spaces between each ending tag `</div>` and opening `<div>` tag, like his:

```
<div id="left-side">
    Hello left
</div><div id="in-the-middle">
    Hello center
</div><div id="right-side">
    Hello right
</div>
```

See live action here: http://jsfiddle.net/LbNGq/

Comment: Thank you for not just for the answer but also for explaining why it wasn't showing up like I wanted it to!

Answer (score 0):

Use your right-side div width as slightly small then it shows in the same column

```
#right-side {
    width: 19%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/8MLRL/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` with `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

try this css script

```
<style type="text/css">
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
     display: inline-block;
}

#left-side {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

#in-the-middle {
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}

#right-side {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```